# A question related to the concept of being "relatively prime"

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

Suppose that I have $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of *natural numbers*.

If I have the equation $ab = 2cd$ and I know that $\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(c,d)=1$, then it follows that I have the following divisibility constraints:
$$a \mid 2d,$$
and
$$c \mid b.$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are correct (but the second assumption $\gcd(c,d)=1$ is not used), For this sort of problems, the theorem to keep in mind is **Euler's Lemma**:
$$\left(x|yz \text{ and } \gcd(x,y)=1\right)\Rightarrow x|z \tag 1$$

Now return to your question $ab=2cd$,using $(1)$ for $x=a$, $y=c$ and $z=2d$  we conclude that $a|2d$ so we can write $2d=qa$ and hence 
$$b=qc$$

and from here follows that $c|b$;

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Elaqqad!  =)

Comment: In English, that's Euler's Lemma, not Gauss''s theorem.

Comment: @BillDubuque Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by Euler's Lemma $\,(c,a)=1,\ c\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\,c\mid b,\ $ so $\ a(b/c) = 2d,\,$ so $\,a\mid 2d$

**Remark** $\ $ Note that $\, ab = 2cd\iff \dfrac{b}c = \dfrac{2d}a\,\ $ so $\,\  c\mid b\iff a\mid 2d$